# Chequear si existe un valor en la base de datos

Tags: java, android, firebase

Intento chequear un valor que introduzco con un `EditText` en la base de datos de Firebase antes de escribir el valor.

Para ello tengo lo siguiente:

```
EditText Username;
Button buttonUser;
public FirebaseDatabase database;
boolean flag=false;
final int Posx = (int) (Math.random() * 1024);
final int Posy = (int) (Math.random() * 512);
public long fechamili=System.currentTimeMillis();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlogin2);

    buttonUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_userlogin);
    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference Usuariosregistrados=database.getReference().child("usuarios").child("userID").child("nombre");


    Usuariosregistrados.orderByValue().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

            Usuario usernameTaken=dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
            String Nombre=Username.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.i( "NOMBRES", "los nombres obtenidos son" + usernameTaken);
            Log.i( "DATOS", " el nombre metido es" + Nombre);


            if(Nombre.equals(usernameTaken)){
                flag = true;

            }
            if(!flag) {
                crearusuario();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText (userlogin2.this, "Username already taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        }
```

Pero no recibo los valores de la base de datos para compararlos. 
¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo a lo que dice juan, tambien podes usar exists() para chequear si el dato en donde lo estas buscando esta o no

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios/"+id+"/nombre");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if(dataSnapshot.exists())
             //existe
           else
          //no existe


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener una sola vez la información ( como parece que es el caso) deberías usar `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` a diferencia del `childAddesListener` este se ejecuta por más que no haya hijos en el nodo de la BD, en cuyo caso el objeto `DataSnapshot` que llega es null, de esa manera puedes chequear.

Ejemplo:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios/"+id+"/nombre");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if(dataSnapshot == null){
          // el nodo no tiene hijos
        }else{
        //hacer algo con el valor
        }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta. Lo que intento hacer es comparar varios datos. El que recojo del EditText con los que existen en la base de datos de Firebase.

Comment: hay algo de la respuesta que no es claro?